# Article date extractor

Tags: beginner, parsing, datetime, web-scraping, rust

I am quite new to Rust and this is my first library written in it. It's an article date extractor heavily inspired by the [original Python library](https://github.com/Webhose/article-date-extractor) as well as its [Haskell port](https://github.com/amir/article-date-extractor).

It is fairly small and most of the logic was taken from the Python library. I want to make sure my Rust code is idiomatic.

This is extract_date.rs:

```
use regex::Regex;
use chrono::NaiveDate;
use reqwest;
use std::io::Read;
use select::document::Document;
use select::predicate::{Name, Attr};
use rustc_serialize::json::Json;
use errors::*;

// Some formats borrowed from https://github.com/amir/article-date-extractor
static FMTS: &'static [&str] = &["%A, %B %e, %Y",
                                 "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%:z",
                                 "/%Y/%m/%d/",
                                 "/%Y/%d/%m/",
                                 "%Y-%m-%d",
                                 "%B %e, %Y",
                                 "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
                                 "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ",
                                 "%B %k, %Y, %H:%M %p",
                                 "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.000000"];

// Use lazy_static to ensure we only compile the regex once
lazy_static! {
    // Regex by Newspaper3k  - https://github.com/codelucas/newspaper/blob/master/newspaper/urls.py
    static ref RE: Regex =
        Regex::new(r"([\./\-_]{0,1}(19|20)\d{2})[\./\-_]{0,1}(([0-3]{0,1}[0-9][\./\-_])|(\w{3,5}[\./\-_]))([0-3]{0,1}[0-9][\./\-]{0,1})").unwrap();
}

// Parse the date, trying out each format
fn parse_date(input: &str) -> Result<NaiveDate> {
    let mut result: Result<NaiveDate> = Err("None of the formats matched the date".into());

    'outer: for fmt in FMTS {
        if let Ok(v) = NaiveDate::parse_from_str(input, fmt) {
            {
                result = Ok(v);
                break 'outer;
            }
        }
    }

    result
}

// Extract date from a URL
fn extract_from_url(url: &str) -> Option<String> {
    if let Some(val) = RE.find(url) {
        return Some(val.as_str().to_string());
    } else {
        return None;
    }
}

// Extract date from JSON-LD
fn extract_from_ldjson<'a>(html: &'a Document) -> Option<String> {
    let mut json_date: Option<String> = None;
    let mut _ldjson: String = String::new();
    if let Some(ldj) = html.find(Attr("type", "application/ld+json")).next() {
        _ldjson = ldj.text();
    } else {
        return None;
    }

    let mut _decoded_ldjson: Json = Json::from_str("{}").unwrap();

    match Json::from_str(&_ldjson) {
        Ok(v) => _decoded_ldjson = v,
        _ => return None,
    }

    if let Some(date_published) = _decoded_ldjson.search("datePublished") {
        if let Some(date) = date_published.as_string() {
            json_date = Some(date.to_string())
        }
    } else if let Some(date_created) = _decoded_ldjson.search("dateCreated") {
        if let Some(date) = date_created.as_string() {
            json_date = Some(date.to_string())
        }
    }

    json_date
}

// Extract date from meta tags
fn extract_from_meta<'a>(html: &'a Document) -> Option<String> {
    let mut meta_date: Option<String> = None;

    'outer: for meta in html.find(Name("meta")) {
        let meta_name: Option<&str> = meta.attr("name");
        let item_prop: Option<&str> = meta.attr("itemprop");
        let http_equiv: Option<&str> = meta.attr("http-equiv");
        let meta_property: Option<&str> = meta.attr("property");

        if let Some(v) = meta_name {
            match v.to_lowercase().as_ref() {
                "pubdate" |
                "publishdate" |
                "timestamp" |
                "dc.date.issued" |
                "date" |
                "sailthru.date" |
                "article.published" |
                "published-date" |
                "article.created" |
                "article_date_original" |
                "cxenseparse:recs:publishtime" |
                "date_published" => {
                    if let Some(ct) = meta.attr("content") {
                        {
                            meta_date = Some(ct.trim().to_string());
                            break 'outer;
                        }
                    }
                }
                _ => {}
            }
        }

        if let Some(v) = item_prop {
            match v.to_lowercase().as_ref() {
                "datepublished" | "datecreated" => {
                    if let Some(ct) = meta.attr("content") {
                        {
                            meta_date = Some(ct.trim().to_string());
                            break 'outer;
                        }
                    }
                }
                _ => {}
            }
        }

        if let Some(v) = http_equiv {
            match v.to_lowercase().as_ref() {
                "date" => {
                    if let Some(ct) = meta.attr("content") {
                        {
                            meta_date = Some(ct.trim().to_string());
                            break 'outer;
                        }
                    }
                }
                _ => {}
            }
        }

        if let Some(v) = meta_property {
            match v.as_ref() {
                "article:published_time" |
                "bt:pubdate" => {
                    if let Some(ct) = meta.attr("content") {
                        {
                            meta_date = Some(ct.trim().to_string());
                            break 'outer;
                        }
                    }
                }
                "og:image" => {
                    if let Some(url) = meta.attr("content") {
                        {
                            meta_date = extract_from_url(url.trim());
                            break 'outer;
                        }
                    }
                }

                _ => {}
            }
        }


    }

    meta_date
}

// Extract from html tags
fn extract_from_html_tag<'a>(html: &'a Document) -> Option<String> {
    lazy_static! {
        static ref TAG_RE: Regex =
            Regex::new(r"(?i)publishdate|pubdate|timestamp|article_date|articledate|date").unwrap();
    }

    let mut date: Option<String> = None;

    'initial: for time in html.find(Name("time")) {
        if let Some(dt) = time.attr("datetime") {
            {
                date = Some(dt.to_string());
                break 'initial;
            }
        } else if let Some("timestamp") = time.attr("class") {
            {
                date = Some(time.text().trim_matches('\n').to_string());
                break 'initial;
            }
        }
    }

    if date.is_none() {
        'outer: for tag in html.find(Name("span")) {
            if let Some("datePublished") = tag.attr("itemprop") {
                if let Some(v) = tag.attr("content") {
                    {
                        date = Some(v.to_string());
                        break 'outer;
                    }
                } else if !tag.text().is_empty() {
                    {
                        date = Some(tag.text().trim_matches('\n').to_string());
                        break 'outer;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // These next three loops are due to the lack of `find_all` method for select.rs library
    if date.is_none() {
        'outer_first: for tag in html.find(Name("span")) {
            if TAG_RE.is_match(tag.attr("class").unwrap_or("")) {
                {
                    date = Some(tag.text().trim_matches('\n').to_string());
                    break 'outer_first;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if date.is_none() {
        'outer_second: for tag in html.find(Name("p")) {
            if TAG_RE.is_match(tag.attr("class").unwrap_or("")) {
                {
                    date = Some(tag.text().trim_matches('\n').to_string());
                    break 'outer_second;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if date.is_none() {
        'outer_third: for tag in html.find(Name("div")) {
            if TAG_RE.is_match(tag.attr("class").unwrap_or("")) {
                {
                    date = Some(tag.text().trim_matches('\n').to_string());
                    break 'outer_third;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    date
}

// Try to extract the date by using each function one by one
/// This function attempts to extract the article date by using several different methods in a row.
/// The following methods are used: extracting the date from url, JSON-LD, meta tags, additional html tags.
///
/// Supported date formats:
///
///
///"%A, %B %e, %Y"
///
///"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%:z"
///
///"/%Y/%m/%d/"
///
///"/%Y/%d/%m/"
///
///"%Y-%m-%d"
///
///"%B %e, %Y"
///
///"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
///
///"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"
///
///"%B %k, %Y, %H:%M %p"
///
///"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.000000"
///
pub fn extract_article_published_date(link: &str, html: Option<String>) -> Result<NaiveDate> {
    let mut body: String = String::new();
    let mut _parsed_body: Option<Document> = None;

    if let Some(v) = extract_from_url(link) {
        return parse_date(&v);
    }

    if html.is_none() {
        if let Ok(mut response) = reqwest::get(link) {
            response.read_to_string(&mut body).unwrap();
            let doc = Document::from(body.as_str());
            _parsed_body = Some(doc);
        } else {
            return Err("Couldn't open the link".into());
        }
    } else {
        _parsed_body = Some(Document::from(html.unwrap().as_str()))
    }

    if let Some(v) = extract_from_url(link) {
        return parse_date(&v);
    } else if let Some(v) = extract_from_ldjson(_parsed_body.as_ref().unwrap()) {
        return parse_date(&v);
    } else if let Some(v) = extract_from_meta(_parsed_body.as_ref().unwrap()) {
        return parse_date(&v);
    } else if let Some(v) = extract_from_html_tag(_parsed_body.as_ref().unwrap()) {
        return parse_date(&v);
    } else {
        return Err("Couldn't find the date to parse".into());
    }
}

// Unit tests
#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use super::extract_from_url;
    use super::parse_date;
    use super::extract_from_meta;
    use super::extract_from_ldjson;
    use super::extract_from_html_tag;
    use chrono::NaiveDate;
    use reqwest;
    use reqwest::Response;
    use std::io::Read;
    use select::document::Document;

    #[test]
    fn parsing_date() {
        assert_eq!(NaiveDate::from_ymd(2015, 11, 30),
                   parse_date("/2015/11/30/").unwrap());
        assert_eq!(NaiveDate::from_ymd(2015, 11, 30),
                   parse_date("/2015/30/11/").unwrap());

        assert!(parse_date("bad_format").is_err());
    }

    #[test]
    fn extracting_from_url() {
        let link: &str = "http://edition.cnn.\
                          com/2015/11/28/opinions/sutter-cop21-paris-preview-two-degrees/index.\
                          html";
        assert_eq!(Some("/2015/11/28/".to_string()), extract_from_url(link));

        let link: &str = "";
        assert_eq!(None, extract_from_url(link));
    }

    #[test]
    fn extracting_from_ldjson() {
        let mut response: Response =
            reqwest::get("https://techcrunch.com/2015/11/30/atlassian-share-price/").unwrap();
        let mut body: String = String::new();
        response.read_to_string(&mut body).unwrap();
        let document: Document = Document::from(body.as_str());

        assert_eq!(Some("2015-12-01T07:50:48Z".to_string()),
                   extract_from_ldjson(&document));
    }

    #[test]
    fn extracting_from_meta() {
        let mut response: Response =
            reqwest::get("https://techcrunch.com/2015/11/30/atlassian-share-price/").unwrap();
        let mut body: String = String::new();
        response.read_to_string(&mut body).unwrap();
        let document: Document = Document::from(body.as_str());

        assert_eq!(Some(("2015-11-30 23:50:48".to_string())),
                   extract_from_meta(&document));
    }

    #[test]
    fn extracting_from_html_tag() {
        let mut response: Response =
            reqwest::get("https://research.googleblog.\
                          com/2017/03/announcing-guetzli-new-open-source-jpeg.html")
                .unwrap();
        let mut body: String = String::new();
        response.read_to_string(&mut body).unwrap();
        let document: Document = Document::from(body.as_str());

        assert_eq!(Some("Thursday, March 16, 2017".to_string()),
                   extract_from_html_tag(&document));
    }
}
```

errors.rs:

```
error_chain! {}
```

lib.rs:

````
/*!
This crate provides a library for extracting the publication date from
an article or a blog plost. It was heavily influenced by both the original
[article-date-extractor](https://github.com/Webhose/article-date-extractor)
written in Python, as well as its [Haskell port](https://github.com/amir/article-date-extractor).

# Example: extracting a date from a news article

```rust
use article_date_extractor::extract_date::extract_article_published_date;

let link = "http://edition.cnn.com/2015/11/28/opinions/sutter-cop21-paris-preview-two-degrees/index.html";
assert!(extract_article_published_date(&link, None).is_ok());
```

*/

#![recursion_limit = "1024"]
extern crate regex;
#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;
extern crate chrono;
extern crate reqwest;
extern crate select;
extern crate rustc_serialize;
#[macro_use]
extern crate error_chain;
pub mod extract_date;
mod errors;
````

Cargo.toml dependencies:

```
[dependencies]
regex = "0.2"
lazy_static = "0.2.2"
chrono = "0.3"
reqwest = "0.4.0"
select = { git = "https://github.com/utkarshkukreti/select.rs" }
rustc-serialize = "0.3"
error-chain = "0.10.0"
```

tests/integration_test.rs:

```
extern crate article_date_extractor;
extern crate chrono;
extern crate reqwest;

#[test]
fn integration_test() {
    use article_date_extractor::extract_date::extract_article_published_date;
    use chrono::NaiveDate;
    use reqwest;
    use std::io::Read;

    let link_1 = "http://edition.cnn.\
                  com/2015/11/28/opinions/sutter-cop21-paris-preview-two-degrees/index.html";
    let link_2 = "https://www.nytimes.\
                  com/2017/03/15/style/meditation-studio-sound-baths-mndfl-new-york.html";
    let link_3 = "http://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-39298218";
    let link_4 = "https://research.googleblog.com/2017/03/announcing-guetzli-new-open-source-jpeg.\
                  html";
    let link_5 = "http://theklog.co/type-of-water-to-wash-face-with/";

    let mut response =
        reqwest::get("http://edition.cnn.\
                      com/2015/11/28/opinions/sutter-cop21-paris-preview-two-degrees/index.html")
            .unwrap();
    let mut body = String::new();
    response.read_to_string(&mut body).unwrap();

    assert_eq!(NaiveDate::from_ymd(2015, 11, 28),
               extract_article_published_date(&link_1, None).unwrap());
    assert_eq!(NaiveDate::from_ymd(2015, 11, 28),
               extract_article_published_date(&link_1, Some(body)).unwrap());

    assert_eq!(NaiveDate::from_ymd(2017, 03, 15),
               extract_article_published_date(&link_2, None).unwrap());

    assert_eq!(NaiveDate::from_ymd(2017, 03, 16),
               extract_article_published_date(&link_3, None).unwrap());

    assert_eq!(NaiveDate::from_ymd(2017, 03, 16),
               extract_article_published_date(&link_4, None).unwrap());

    assert_eq!(NaiveDate::from_ymd(2017, 03, 16),
               extract_article_published_date(&link_5, None).unwrap());

    assert!((extract_article_published_date("", None)).is_err());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to everything mentioned in [the other answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/158655/32521)...

1. If you are going to rely on nightly to avoid the need to say `'static` in a `static`, use it fully. Just say `&[&str]`
2. I've **never** needed to use loop labels. There's almost always better solutions.
3. Instead of looping across the formats in `parse_date`, use the `Iterator` and `Option` adapters.
4. Speaking of which, learn **all** the methods on `Option` and `Iterator`. They will save you much time. `map` is invaluable. See `extract_from_url`.
5. There are too many useless comments. Why say `// Extract date from a URL` right before the method `extract_from_url`. What benefit does that get you? If you have something useful to say about a function, use doc comments.
6. Don't specify lifetimes unless you use them. See `extract_from_ldjson` and many others.
7. Don't define variables with dummy values (`_ldjson`, `_decoded_ldjson`).
8. Seriously, learn `Option::and_then`, `Option::map`, `Option::or`, etc.
9. There are many strange extra braces scattered about, mostly in the `if let` statements.
10. The if let for `meta.attr("content")` is repeated in each clause, but if it's ever `None`, we should just fail immediately. Pull it out and check it early.

```
static FMTS: &[&str] = &["%A, %B %e, %Y",
                         "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%:z",
                         "/%Y/%m/%d/",
                         "/%Y/%d/%m/",
                         "%Y-%m-%d",
                         "%B %e, %Y",
                         "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
                         "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ",
                         "%B %k, %Y, %H:%M %p",
                         "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.000000"];

fn parse_date(input: &str) -> Result<NaiveDate> {
    FMTS.iter()
        .flat_map(|fmt| NaiveDate::parse_from_str(input, fmt))
        .next()
        .ok_or("None of the formats matched the date".into())
}

fn extract_from_url(url: &str) -> Option<String> {
    RE.find(url).map(|val| val.as_str().to_string())
}

fn extract_from_ldjson(html: &Document) -> Option<String> {
    html.find(Attr("type", "application/ld+json"))
        .next()
        .map(|ldj| ldj.text())
        .and_then(|ldjson| Json::from_str(&ldjson).ok())
        .and_then(|_decoded_ldjson| {
            let published = _decoded_ldjson
                .search("datePublished")
                .and_then(|date| date.as_string())
                .map(|date| date.to_string());

            let created = _decoded_ldjson
                .search("dateCreated")
                .and_then(|date| date.as_string())
                .map(|date| date.to_string());

            published.or(created)
        })
}

fn meta_name_denotes_date(meta_name: &str) -> bool {
    match meta_name.to_lowercase().as_str() {
        "pubdate" |
        "publishdate" |
        "timestamp" |
        "dc.date.issued" |
        "date" |
        "sailthru.date" |
        "article.published" |
        "published-date" |
        "article.created" |
        "article_date_original" |
        "cxenseparse:recs:publishtime" |
        "date_published" => true,
        _ => false,
    }
}

fn meta_itemprop_denotes_date(item_prop: &str) -> bool {
    match item_prop.to_lowercase().as_str() {
        "datepublished" | "datecreated" => true,
        _ => false
    }
}

fn meta_http_equiv_denotes_date(http_equiv: &str) -> bool {
    match http_equiv.to_lowercase().as_str() {
        "date" => true,
        _ => false,
    }
}

fn meta_property_denotes_date(meta_property: &str) -> bool {
    match meta_property {
        "article:published_time" | "bt:pubdate" => true,
        _ => false,
    }
}  

fn extract_from_meta(html: &Document) -> Option<String> {
    html.find(Name("meta")).flat_map(|meta| {
        let content = match meta.attr("content") {
            Some(c) => c,
            None => return None,
        };
        let content = content.trim();

        let meta_name = meta.attr("name");
        let item_prop = meta.attr("itemprop");
        let http_equiv = meta.attr("http-equiv");
        let meta_property = meta.attr("property");

        let content_has_date = meta_name.map(meta_name_denotes_date)
            .or_else(|| item_prop.map(meta_itemprop_denotes_date))
            .or_else(|| http_equiv.map(meta_http_equiv_denotes_date))
            .or_else(|| meta_property.map(meta_property_denotes_date))
            .unwrap_or(false);

        if content_has_date {
            Some(content.to_string())
        } else if Some("og:image") == meta_property {
           extract_from_url(content)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }).next()
}
```

At this point I grew tired of fixing the same type of errors over and over, so hopefully there's nothing interesting left to comment on in the rest of the code ^_^

Answer (score 5):

### Type deduction

First of all, there is no need to specify types everywhere. The Rust compiler supports type deduction, so

```
let mut _ldjson: String = String::new();
```

is same as

```
let mut _ldjson = String::new();
```

Use type deduction whenever it is possible. DRY. BTW, I'd recommend to avoid names that start with underscores: readability suffers.

### Statements vs expressions

Almost everything in Rust is an *expression*. Prefer *expressions* to *statements*. It allows to simplify code and avoid unnecessary initializations.

```
let mut _decoded_ldjson: Json = Json::from_str("{}").unwrap();

match Json::from_str(&_ldjson) {
    Ok(v) => _decoded_ldjson = v,
    _ => return None,
}
```

vs

```
let decoded_ldjson = match Json::from_str(&ldjson) {
   Ok(v) => v,
   _ => return None;
};
```

This approach also allows to make more values immutable which in most cases leads to more effective code.

### Branching

Rust standard library provides [functions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.or_else) with which unnecessary branching in the code can be avoided. Let's combine this tip with the previous ones and see what happens:

```
pub fn extract_article_published_date(link: &str, html: Option<String>) -> Result<NaiveDate> {
    let mut body: String = String::new();
    let mut _parsed_body: Option<Document> = None;

    if let Some(v) = extract_from_url(link) {
        return parse_date(&v);
    }

    if html.is_none() {
        if let Ok(mut response) = reqwest::get(link) {
            response.read_to_string(&mut body).unwrap();
            let doc = Document::from(body.as_str());
            _parsed_body = Some(doc);
        } else {
            return Err("Couldn't open the link".into());
        }
    } else {
        _parsed_body = Some(Document::from(html.unwrap().as_str()))
    }

    if let Some(v) = extract_from_url(link) {
        return parse_date(&v);
    } else if let Some(v) = extract_from_ldjson(_parsed_body.as_ref().unwrap()) {
        return parse_date(&v);
    } else if let Some(v) = extract_from_meta(_parsed_body.as_ref().unwrap()) {
        return parse_date(&v);
    } else if let Some(v) = extract_from_html_tag(_parsed_body.as_ref().unwrap()) {
        return parse_date(&v);
    } else {
        return Err("Couldn't find the date to parse".into());
    }
}
```

=>

```
pub fn extract_article_published_date(link: &str, html: &str) -> Result<NaiveDate> {
    let doc = Document::from(html);

    extract_from_url(link)
      .or_else(|| extract_from_ldjson(doc.as_ref()))
      .or_else(|| extract_from_meta(doc.as_ref()))
      .or_else(|| extract_from_html_tag(doc.as_ref()))
      .ok_or("Couldn't find the date to parse".into())
      .map(|v| parse_date(&v))
}
```

That's how idiomatic Rust code looks like!

I've also deleted code that downloads web page, because there is no need for it. This move frees library from network code and allows users use their favorite libraries for http requests (e.g. [hyper](https://crates.io/crates/hyper)).

Comment: *names that start with underscores: readability suffers* — even more, in Rust, a leading underscore is explicit indication that the variable is deliberately **unused**. That is not the case here.

Comment: I think I was trying to suppress `unused code` warnings and instead of using `#[allow(dead_code)]` I did this. My bad, will fix it.